# Making a clock in python using a clock module

Tags: python-3.x

Hello this is my first question!

Can someone please tell me if there is a clock module in python and how i can use it to make a standard and binary clock?

I have an intermediate coding experience in python yet i dont know how to make a clock.

Would be appreciated!

Comment: What are you expecting from the clock module? Are you looking for a GUI related module to draw the clock or getting the correct time?

Comment: Mainly just getting the correct time then making a gui

Comment: Get the current time using `datetime` module and `datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: There is a documentation on 'time'. You may start from there. https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

Comment: Im wondering if i can use three variables like hours minutes and seconds, but how do i print them side by side without adding them